# Cannot delete pandas row using index inplace

Tags: pandas, drop

In a complex code, I can't delete pandas row using index.
Here is a code simplified:

We declare a pandas df:
I have a dataframe from a csv file:

```
dataset.head()
```

[image: Output:]

As you can see, i deleted row with index=0
But impossible to delete other row using index:

```
dataset.drop(dataset.index[2],inplace=True)
dataset[dataset.index == 2]
```

[image: output]

I delete inplace. I don't undestand. Can you help me please for this a priori basic problem?
Thanks a lot.
Theo

Comment: try `dataset.drop(2, inplace=True)`

Comment: The value at `df.index[2]` is not `2`.  It is `5`.  Use `drop` as @dzakyputra suggested.

Comment: O thanks a lot. It works as @dzakyputra suggested. It maked me mad!

Comment: @piRSquared Why is there an offset (5 inplace 2)?

Comment: I'm looking at the output you've provided from `df.head()`.  The value of `5` is in the third index position.  When you use `df.index[2]` you are looking at the third index value.  `df.index[0]` is the first, `df.index[1]` is the second, and `df.index[2]` is the third.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset.index != 2]
```